# NextJS TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect') while building

Tags: reactjs, next.js, aws-amplify, pnpm

```
2023-06-29T16:36:01.821Z [WARNING]: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')

2023-06-29T16:36:01.860Z [WARNING]: > Export encountered errors on following paths:
                                    /
                                    /_error: /404
                                    /_error: /500
                                    /admin/dashboard
```

Error while building on AWS Amplify. It was working earlier but not working now on the same code with different content updates in my components.

I tried passing props to all the components and thought to amplify caused issues due to that, but that isn't the case.

After reading https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24928#issuecomment-1257811965 Since I was using `pnpm` I got to know that there's some issue with linking only.

So I removed the cached `node_modules` and it worked!.

After that I re-added the caching logic of `node_modules` but that started to fail again.